# Identify this language

Tags: syntax, programming-languages

This might be a domain-specific language (DSL). I pulled it from the `GMC Inspire Designer` [user manual](http://lfpp.csa.canon.com/main/view_media.jsp?WebLogicSession=0w1yYkvpsxBmN2yZdT1gVhL2nr0l1PmSbngLc8LTwmCthqcLG14J!1210658755&CONTENT%3C%3Ecnt_id=10134198673404461&FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=9852723696641506&bmUID=lIqFZ8T). It's like C++/Java/C# but I don't think any of those has a `function` keyword:

```
function stringIsLong(String Parameter1) : Bool
{
    return Parameter1.Length > 20;
}
```

GMC Inspire runs on Windows and Linux, possibly under Mono, but I have no idea.

Comment: The relevant portion (17) of the referenced document starts at p. 1800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading deep in the PDF you provided the link for,  there is a reference to developing DLLs in C or C#.   I would guess that it is a slightly customised version of one of those.

Comment: Yeah, that' my take on it. I'm meeting someone tomorrow who might have the answer and will report back.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't able to get a definitive answer for this.

Comment: From pg 1916 of InspireDesigner-User_Manual-V11.0.0.2.pdf : "The syntax for scripting is object-oriented, taking much of its formulation from C ++"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sute, but this seems like Javascript function, here the link about [javascript functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp), in this case there is the `function` keyword.

Here a example:

```js
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
    return p1 * p2;              // The function returns the product of p1 and p2
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. Javascript doesn't support function parameter types.